# How to write a Loop for a Dummy?

Tags: php, foreach

this is probably an easy question, but I am not really a coder.  I maintain a website for a group I belong to, and there are some php forms.  I am trying to enhance a form, and I have added this php code, which works (see below).  My question is, how can I put this code into a loop so that it repeats 10 times, for "01", "02", etc., "10" strings (code below is for "01" of the series)?  Thanks for any help.

```
//Clean up the Photo Title & Maker Name to remove non-standard chars and replace spaces with underscores and generate a suggested fliename

$photo_01_clean = str_replace(" ","75357",$photo_01_name);
$photo_01_clean1 = str_replace("@","at",$photo_01_clean);
$photo_01_clean2 = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $photo_01_clean1);
$photo_01_clean3 = str_replace("75357","_",$photo_01_clean2);

$photo_01_maker_clean = str_replace(" ","75357",$photo_01_maker_name);
$photo_01_maker_clean1 = str_replace("@","at",$photo_01_maker_clean);
$photo_01_maker_clean2 = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $photo_01_maker_clean1);
$photo_01_maker_clean3 = str_replace("75357","_",$photo_01_maker_clean2);

$photo_01_filename_gen = $club_code."-01-".$photo_01_clean3."-".$photo_01_maker_clean3.".jpg";
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd require a for loop control structure. You can find tons of resources that would teach you how to do it. [example](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 1):

Var i;
      For (i =1; i<11; i++)
             Execute Code here.